# Integrated webcam /dev/video0 sends no data

Tags: ubuntu, camera

The integrated webcam on my machine is detected (`/dev/video0` exists and the webcam led turns on when an client app starts using it (e.g. cheese, ffplay etc). Most application sends errors about the webcam not sending any data.

Most posts I could find seem to suggest that a lock key disabling hardware access to the webcam is causing the issue (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> on most laptop) In my case, no such key is present on the keyboard.

A hardware failure is not impossible, but seems highly unlikely given that the laptop was extremely carefully handled.

```
Hardware: Lenovo Ideapad 15

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
```

```
$ uname -r
5.19.0-45-generic
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-device
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:05:00.3-3):
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
/dev/media0
```

```
$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jun 25 18:09 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Jun 25 18:09 /dev/video1
```

```
$ ffplay /dev/video0
ffplay version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2003-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

```
$ fswebcam
--- Opening /dev/video0...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video0 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 352x288.
--- Capturing frame...
Timed out waiting for frame!
No frames captured.
```

Comment: The small resolution of 384x288 suggests this might not be a general-purpose web camera, but an infrared one for face identification (Windows Hello etc.). Normal webcam utilities might not know how to use an infrared camera. Try explicitly using `/dev/video1` instead.

Comment: Does `id` show `video` among your supplemental groups? (and whatever the group of `/dev/media0` is). If not, `sudo adduser $USER video` followed by logout/login (changes made to `/etc/groups` are applied by `login`).

Comment: Yes my user is part of the video group, I made sure to reboot after all changes made to the groups

Comment: I suspect the integrated webcam is physically broken: external webcams work fine. I don't know how to confirm this hypothesis however